# Kendo View Model Not Binding with DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I would like to bind my form to a kedno observable view model.  I can get it to work with a hard coded value but not a DataSource. I have verified that the data source has one item in the view and I can fetch it.  See code below.  Any ideas?    Thanks

```
 //Hard coded first name binds to my form correctly
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        first_name: "John"
    });

 kendo.bind($("form"), viewModel);




//This doesn't bind correctly
var sharableDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     transport: {
            read: {
                     url: "myurl goes here" ,
                     dataType: "json"
                   }
                }
  });

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
       datasource: sharableDataSource
    });

kendo.bind($("form"), viewModel);



//HTML I am binding to
 <li>First Name <span class="value" data-bind="text: first_name"> </span></</li>
```

Comment: @Downvoter please explain the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

What html are you binding with the second viewModel  ?
And these aren't both on the same page right ?

Comment: Only one set of HTML.  I try the first viewmodel and it works then comment it out and try the second viewmodel and it doesn't work.  I'm guessing you can't assign a datasource directly to the observable, but i don't know.